# Simplify removes relational term in Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to simplify an expression using sympy but the relational terms seem to disappear. A toy example is as follows:

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
z = Symbol('z')
```

If I run:

```
z * Eq(x, y)
```

Then the output is:

```
z*(x == y)
```

But if I try to simplify this using:

```
simplify(z * Eq(x, y))
```

Then the output is:

```
z
```

Which I would not expect - should I expect this behaviour and if so, is there any way to prevent simplify from removing the relational term?

Thanks.

Comment: what did you mean with that equation?

Comment: Maybe you are trying logic operations such as: `And(z,Eq(x,y))`, in such case `simplify` works perfectly.

Comment: I was hoping that sympy would interpret Eq(x,y) as 1 or 0 depending on whether it was true or false

Comment: Then you should use: `f = Piecewise((1,Eq(x,y)),(0,True))` and then: `simplify(z*f)`

Comment: When you confirm that's what you want, i will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic and arithmetic operations cannot be combined to make such operations.

**Supposing:**

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
f = symbols('f', cls=Function)
```

**For arithmetic operation:**

```
xeqy = Piecewise((1,Eq(x,y)),(0,True)) # {1 for x = y, 0 otherwise}
f = z * xeqy                           # {z for x = y, 0 otherwise}
simplify(f)
```

**For logical operation:**

```
f = And(z,Eq(x,y))                     # z ∧ (x = y)
simplify(f)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's pretty clunky but it works and makes sense.